# gzip without mod_gzip nor mod_deflate and pre gzipped files

Tags: php, .htaccess, gzip

My hosting company does not support mod_gzip nor mod_deflate.

I must gzip .js and css files

I have pre-compressed the files.

I use Joomla, and to add scripts to the document, I must use a PHP file that serves the .js.gz files whenever the encoding is accepted by the user (example of PHP joomla code):

```
$document = &JFactory::getDocument();

    $document->addScript($jQueryPath);
```

I added the directive below to .htaccess; however, the browsers are not decompressing the .js.gz files

```
# Add some gzip to the bunch
AddEncoding x-gzip .gz 
<FilesMatch \.js.gz$>
        ForceType text/javascript
        Header set Content-Encoding "gzip"
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch \.css.gz$>
        ForceType text/css
        Header set Content-Encoding "gzip"
</FilesMatch>

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^.+\.(js|css)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.gz -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.gz [L,QSA,NC,NS]
```

Could anyone help on how to gzip under the described conditions?

Thank you,

Comment: Personally, I'd shortcut the whole situation and find a more competent hosting company.

Comment: Hosting company aside, it just can make sense to have pre-calculated compression as often the files don't change and there is no need for the server to do the same job all over again. Sort of caching.

Answer (score 0):

Most php installations come with the Zlib extension which
lets you manipulate gzip files.

Take a look at these php manual pages to accomplish what you asked for:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzcompress.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzdeflate.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzencode.php

you can use the $_SERVER superglobal to check the Accept Encoding Header:

```
if (substr_count($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'deflate'))
{
// DO STUFF HERE
}
elseif (substr_count($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'gzip'))
{
// DO STUFF HERE
}
```